# How do I get the name of command that raised error in discord.py?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to make some kind of command log and I want it not only send that "some command was just executed", but also send if user raised any errors while trying to use this command (missing argument/permission and so on). I want to implement it using `on_command_error()`, but I still need to know which command raised the error. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Is something like this helping you? [Example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612). There are many errors you can implement, just have a look what `error, commands.????` gives you.
If you set up the listener/event `on_command_error` the bot will tell you after executing a command if there was an error with your input etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you get the ctx from the failed command, you can access the command name with `ctx.invoked_with` or `ctx.command` if you want the full command object.

```py
...
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    command = ctx.invoked_with
```

See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=notfound#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.command